# Python weighted choosing that works with very large numbers

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, random

I have written a function to choose randomly with weights from very large data sets in which the weight of elements can be several thousands.

The input of the function is a flat `dict`, the keys can be any object and the values must be positive `int`s, and the values represent the count of the element within the data set, the format of the input should be the same as that of `Counter`, anyway I constructed the objects using `Counter` but I manipulate them as `dict`s.

As I wrote above, the values can be extremely large, the function returns one element.
I know I can use something like this:

```py
keys = dic.keys()
vals = dic.values()
random.choices(keys, weights=vals, k=1)[0]
```

Or even this:

```py
random.choice(list(dic.elements()))
```

But I don't think these methods to be cost-effective, memory consumption is a huge problem here and these methods are slow and/or memory-intensive. And I think unpacking the data set to flatten the data set to a extremely long list of the same elements repeating countless times to be extremely dumb.

Instead I based my function on `range`, the idea is to calculate which `range` a number must fall in in order to get the corresponding element, then generate a random number in `range(total)` and determine which sub-range the number falls in, and return the corresponding element.

### Code

```py
import random
from typing import Any

def weighted_choice(dic: dict) -> Any:
    if not isinstance(dic, dict):
        raise TypeError('The argument of the function should be a dictionary')
    keys = list(dic.keys())
    vals = list(dic.values())
    if set(type(i) for i in vals) != {int}:
        raise TypeError('The values of the argument must be integers')
    if 0 in vals:
        raise ValueError('The values of the argument shouldn\'t contain 0')
    total = sum(vals)
    stored = 0
    items = list()
    for k, v in zip(keys, vals):
        items.append((range(stored, stored+v), k))
        stored += v
    choice = random.randrange(total)
    for r, i in items:
        if choice in r:
            return i
```

### Example

```py
starting_letters = {
    "a": 8061,
    "b": 5413,
    "c": 9996,
    "d": 6328,
    "e": 4829,
    "f": 3846,
    "g": 3261,
    "h": 3928,
    "i": 5020,
    "j": 801,
    "k": 890,
    "l": 3359,
    "m": 6032,
    "n": 2175,
    "o": 3068,
    "p": 9293,
    "q": 553,
    "r": 4307,
    "s": 10387,
    "t": 5019,
    "u": 4404,
    "v": 1628,
    "w": 1789,
    "x": 144,
    "y": 320,
    "z": 379
}

letter_frequency = {
    'a': 80183,
    's': 54738,
    'm': 28847,
    'r': 66553,
    'd': 28914,
    'v': 8877,
    'k': 6103,
    'o': 64730,
    'n': 63640,
    'i': 80469,
    'c': 42724,
    'l': 52184,
    'b': 17558,
    't': 63928,
    'e': 100093,
    'u': 34981,
    'f': 11308,
    'p': 29325,
    'y': 19245,
    'g': 20298,
    'h': 24064,
    'x': 2975,
    'w': 6020,
    'j': 1440,
    'q': 1741,
    'z': 2997
}

print(weighted_choice(starting_letters))
print(weighted_choice(letter_frequency))
```

### Output

```
h
e
```

### Performance

```
In [525]: keys = list(letter_frequency.keys())

In [526]: vals = list(letter_frequency.values())

In [527]: random.choices(keys, weights=vals, k=1)[0]
Out[527]: 'i'

In [528]: %timeit random.choices(keys, weights=vals, k=1)[0]
2.74 µs ± 278 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [529]: %memit random.choices(keys, weights=vals, k=1)[0]
peak memory: 144.55 MiB, increment: 0.00 MiB

In [530]: counter = Counter(letter_frequency)

In [531]: random.choice(list(counter.elements()))
Out[531]: 'r'

In [532]: %timeit random.choice(list(counter.elements()))
21.3 ms ± 1.84 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [533]: %memit random.choice(list(counter.elements()))
peak memory: 162.07 MiB, increment: 17.86 MiB

In [534]: weighted_choice(letter_frequency)
Out[534]: 'l'

In [535]: %timeit weighted_choice(letter_frequency)
16.3 µs ± 272 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [536]: %memit weighted_choice(letter_frequency)
peak memory: 142.69 MiB, increment: 0.00 MiB
```

I intend to use this function in my project to generate pseudowords using Markov chain, and I want to make the function be as efficient as possible, I would like to vectorize the function using `pandas` and `numpy`, I think truth indexing would be extremely useful in this situation and vectorization would speed things up tremendously here, but I don't know if putting `range`s in a `DataFrame` column is a good idea.

How can this script be vectorized?

Comment: Your `%memit` output shows `increment: 0.00 MiB`. I.e., pretty much *nothing*, as you'd expect from this tiny data. You call that "memory-intensive" and "memory consumption is a huge problem"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`random.choices()` does not unpack/flatten the data. It uses the cumulative weights.  First it picks a random value from 0 - the max cumulative weight. Then uses `bisect.bisect()` to map that back to the population.

If you pass in `weights`, `random.choices()` calculates the cumulative weights. If you call it many times it would be more efficient to precalculate and save the cumulative weights (see `itertools.accumulate()`) and pass that in to `random.choices()`

Your code implements the same idea as `random.choices()`, except the library code uses a binary search rather than a linear search like your code.  It is possible for small populations the linear search might be faster because of the overhead of the binary search. For large populations the binary search should be faster.

FYI near the top of the documentation for [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/random.html) is a link to the Python [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.9/Lib/random.py) for the `random` module.  You can look at the source code for `choices` to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [walrus operator](https://realpython.com/lessons/assignment-expressions/) and a generator expression can reduce the runtime and memory-consumption of your final loop. Consider this small change:

```
stored = 0
items = ((range(stored, (stored := stored + v)), k) for k, v in zip(keys, vals))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Performance

- If you're going to call this function with different dictionaries
  each time, then there is really not much to be done. Most of the time
  is spent creating the lists and optimizing the logic in python really
  doesn't speed it up much from what I've tried.
- If you're going to call this function multiple times with the same dict, then I have quite a bit of speedup with numpy:

```py
def weighted_choice_draw_n(dic: dict,n) -> Any:
    if not isinstance(dic, dict):
        raise TypeError("The argument of the function should be a dictionary")

    keys = {}
    for i,k in enumerate((dic.keys())):
        if not isinstance(i,int):
            raise TypeError("The values of the argument must be integers")
        keys[i] = k

    probs = np.fromiter(dic.values(),dtype=int)
    if not np.all(probs):
        raise ValueError("The values of the argument shouldn't contain 0")

    choices = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(probs)), size = n, p = probs/np.sum(probs))

    return [keys[index] for index in choices]
```

100k draws:

```
function [weighted_choice_draw_n](100000,) finished in 20 ms
```

Comment: I believe the start of your loop `for i,k in enumerate((dic.keys())):` contains a logical error, I think you didn't want to iterate over the `.keys()` view but rather `.items()` view, since the indexes will always be `int`s and that check is meant for values.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have refined my algorithm with `itertools.accumulate` and `bisect.bisect`, I am implementing exactly the same idea as the original code (and `random.choices`), the only difference is that it is much more performant now.

The code:

```py
import random
from bisect import bisect
from itertools import accumulate
from typing import Any

def weighted_choice(dic: dict) -> Any:
    if not isinstance(dic, dict):
        raise TypeError('The argument of the function should be a dictionary')
    choices, weights = zip(*dic.items())
    if set(map(type, weights)) != {int}:
        raise TypeError('The values of the argument must be integers')
    if 0 in weights:
        raise ValueError('The values of the argument shouldn\'t contain 0')
    accreted = list(accumulate(weights))
    chosen = random.randrange(accreted[-1])
    return choices[bisect(accreted, chosen)]
```

Example:

```py
from collections import Counter
letter_frequency = {
    'a': 80183,
    's': 54738,
    'm': 28847,
    'r': 66553,
    'd': 28914,
    'v': 8877,
    'k': 6103,
    'o': 64730,
    'n': 63640,
    'i': 80469,
    'c': 42724,
    'l': 52184,
    'b': 17558,
    't': 63928,
    'e': 100093,
    'u': 34981,
    'f': 11308,
    'p': 29325,
    'y': 19245,
    'g': 20298,
    'h': 24064,
    'x': 2975,
    'w': 6020,
    'j': 1440,
    'q': 1741,
    'z': 2997
}
test = Counter([weighted_choice(letter_frequency) for i in range(10000)])
print(test.most_common())
```

Output

```
[('e', 1098), ('i', 899), ('a', 897), ('o', 746), ('t', 716), ('r', 710), ('n', 665), ('s', 588), ('l', 576), ('c', 483), ('u', 367), ('p', 335), ('d', 296), ('m', 290), ('h', 269), ('y', 215), ('g', 205), ('b', 177), ('f', 140), ('w', 88), ('v', 81), ('k', 73), ('z', 36), ('x', 25), ('q', 16), ('j', 9)]
```

Performance

```
In [137]: %load_ext memory_profiler

In [138]: %%timeit
     ...: choices, weights = zip(*letter_frequency.items())
     ...: random.choices(choices, weights, k=1)
5.42 µs ± 345 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [139]: %%timeit
     ...: choices, weights = zip(*letter_frequency.items())
     ...: random.choices(choices, weights, k=1)
5.51 µs ± 387 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [140]: %timeit weighted_choice(letter_frequency)
4.85 µs ± 277 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [141]: %%timeit
     ...: choices, weights = zip(*letter_frequency.items())
     ...: random.choices(choices, weights, k=1)
5.37 µs ± 326 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [142]: %timeit weighted_choice(letter_frequency)
4.89 µs ± 345 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [143]: %%memit
     ...: choices, weights = zip(*letter_frequency.items())
     ...: random.choices(choices, weights, k=1)
peak memory: 143.24 MiB, increment: 0.24 MiB

In [144]: %memit weighted_choice(letter_frequency)
peak memory: 143.25 MiB, increment: 0.00 MiB

In [145]: %%memit
     ...: choices, weights = zip(*letter_frequency.items())
     ...: random.choices(choices, weights, k=1)
peak memory: 143.26 MiB, increment: 0.00 MiB

In [146]: %memit weighted_choice(letter_frequency)
peak memory: 143.26 MiB, increment: 0.00 MiB
```

My code manages to beat `random.choices` at speed while making three checks that literally do nothing in most cases, they just throw exceptions if anyone looking for trouble deliberately tests with edge cases, but their overhead is significant.

Although it goes without saying, `random.choices` checks if the lengths of choices and weights do not match, since I am using `dict`s (actually `Counter`s generalized), the lengths will match.

If I discard all the checks and just test the execution:

```
In [147]: %%timeit
     ...: choices, weights = zip(*letter_frequency.items())
     ...: accreted = list(accumulate(weights))
     ...: chosen = random.randrange(accreted[-1])
     ...: choices[bisect(accreted, chosen)]
4.56 µs ± 325 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Exclude the unpack overhead:

```
In [148]: choices, weights = zip(*letter_frequency.items())

In [149]: %%timeit
     ...: accreted = list(accumulate(weights))
     ...: chosen = random.randrange(accreted[-1])
     ...: choices[bisect(accreted, chosen)]
2.15 µs ± 205 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [150]: %timeit random.choices(choices, weights, k=1)
2.9 µs ± 256 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

My code beats `random.choices` at time complexity.